# How do we create python webservices for android(like php) to be put on server side..?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-services

I am trying to connect my android application with webservices. Is there any possible way to create the  webservices in python.I am not able to find any good examples over the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using frameworks such as [Django](http://djangoproject.com) or [flask](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjR3-Kn4JXXAhWIPY8KHf5qD54QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fflask.pocoo.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw3xZae5nbc7873HpB2xmno8).